# VAR model: How to get bootstrapped 95% prediction interval?

Tags: r, time-series, prediction, forecasting, vector-auto-regression

95% prediction interval for the **VAR model** can be obtained this way (**vars** library):

```
library(vars)
data(Canada)

series_mod = window(Canada, start = c(1990, 1), end = c(2000, 4))
mod = VAR(series_mod, p = 2, type = "const")

predict(mod, n.ahead = 4, ci = 0.95)
```

But what if I would like to get **bootstrapped** 95% prediction interval? How can I calculate it? Say, **Arima** in **forecast** library has parameters for this:

```
forecast(model, ..., bootstrap = T, npaths = 10000)
```

But what about VAR model?